# WordPress Function Falling to Front of Line/Sentence/Code

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php $options = get_option('kittens_options'); if ($options['copyright']!="") echo $options['copyright']; else echo '&copy; '.date('Y').' '.bloginfo('name').'. All Rights Reserved.'; ?>
```

Works perfectly except `'.bloginfo('name').'` although properly showing what it's suppose to, falls out of sequence in the sentence structure.

So what should show as:

*© 2012 Testing. All Rights Reserved.*

shows as:

*Testing© 2012. All Rights Reserved.*

Since `'.bloginfo('name').'` isn't a native PHP function does it need to be filtered or escaped or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's becauase [`bloginfo`<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) is an output function. It does output but not return the string. You need a return function, try with adding `get_` in front: [`get_bloginfo`<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

Function with `get_` at the beginning of their name often return strings instead of outputting them in wordpress, like the `get_option` function you already use.

Code-Example:

```
if ("" == ($copyright = $options['copyright'])) 
    $copyright = '&copy; '.date('Y').' '.get_bloginfo('name').'. All Rights Reserved.'
    ;                                  # ^^^^ #
echo $copyright;
```

Comment: You're welcome. And rmember if something does not turn out well with a function you use, check the codex website which has one page for each wordpress function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_bloginfo('name')` instead of `bloginfo('name')`

```
<?php $options = get_option('kittens_options'); if ($options['copyright']!="") echo $options['copyright']; else echo '&copy; '.date('Y').' '.get_bloginfo('name').'. All Rights Reserved.'; ?>
```

Reference: [**wordpress**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).